# Is there anyway to draw a widget over Flutter Webview

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm using flutter_webview_plugin and I need a close button on top of my flutter webview. Is there a way to draw another widget over webview?
if yes share me an example.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_webview_plugin

Only plugins implemented using platform view support that like https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/webview_flutter.

Comment: I don't find anything to listen to URL change in this plugin. Is there any way?

Comment: Right, that's not yet supported. Upvote and follow https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27729 (perhaps also https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27910)

Comment: what is the solution for now?

Comment: Waiting for this to be fixed or creating a pull request that fixes that yourself. There is one to notify when a page starts loading or finished loading https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/996. You could get that with a Git dependency if this would fulfill your need.